# Azure Data Factory Error: 'activity' is not a recognized function

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to adding the following to the directory in Azure Data Factory

```
sales/@{activity('Lookup Old Watermark').output.firstRow.table_name}/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy')}/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'MM')}/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dd')}/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'HH')}
```

But I'm getting the error:

> 'activity' is not a recognized function

See this screenshot:

[image]

Any thoughts?

I should mention, I'm following the steps listed in the image below:
[image]

Comment: I have run into some odd results in the past using inline code like this. I would try using the expression builder and concat instead just to see if you get different results.

Comment: Hi Joel, can you elaborate?

Comment: I didn't consider before that this was in a Dataset. @BhanunagasaiVamsi is correct, you'll need to build the value in the pipeline and set it as a Dataset parameter. This blog post may help: https://causewaysolutions.com/blog/creating-reusable-datasets-in-azure-data-factory-with-parameters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got same error:**

[image: Re1]

The reason for the error is: `@activity` is recognized only inside the pipeline, but not dataset

To resolve this error, we need to pass the dynamic content to dataset parameter. Try using the following approach

**Step 1:** Open dataset and go to parameter section, create parameter.
[image: Ref1]

[image: Ref3]

[image: Ref4]

**Step 2:** Go to connection section and add dynamic content `sales/@{dataset().directort}`.

[image: Ref5]

**Step 3:** After that, Go to Sink add dynamic content.

**In my scenario this my dynamic content:** `sales/@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Prop_0}/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy')}/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'MM')}/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dd')}/@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'HH')}`

[image: Ref6]

**Output:**

[image: Ref8]

Comment: Hi BhanunagasaiVamsi, thanks for reaching out. I tried to follow your suggestion, but I am now getting the error ```ADLS Gen2 operation failed for: Operation returned an invalid status code 'BadRequest'. Account: 'xxxxxxx'. FileSystem: '2022-08-15T16:17:43.9645966Z.CSV'. ErrorCode: 'InvalidResourceName'. Message: 'The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.'. RequestId: 'c7c10f26-701f-0061-56c2-b0decb000000'. TimeStamp: 'Mon, 15 Aug 2022 16:18:42 GMT'.., 'BadRequest',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'```

Comment: Hi BhanunagasaiVamsi, I have updated the question